# Python3 how to decode json which contain string with \xe

Tags: python-3.x

```
import json
txt = '{"fundcode":"110022","name":"\xe6\x98\x93\xe6\x96\xb9\xe8\xbe\xbe\xe6\xb6\x88\xe8\xb4\xb9\xe8\xa1\x8c\xe4\xb8\x9a",' \
      '"jzrq":"2017-11-20","dwjz":"2.3020","gsz":"2.3203","gszzl":"0.79","gztime":"2017-11-21 11:30"}'
ret = json.loads(txt)
print(ret)
```

Errors Tips like below:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xe6' in position 32: illegal multibyte sequence

Comment: Try utf-8 instead.

Comment: where are you receiving that value of txt from? @Mario7

Comment: from a url http://fundgz.1234567.com.cn/js/110022.js?rt=0.5198424438182809 ,I download it  use python urllib @yklsga